# libjson-rpc-cpp with int64 not supported?

Tags: c++, json, rpc, json-rpc

I was looking for a Json RPC library for C++, and, after several ones I tried, I found https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp as the best so far.

It works very well for my needs, except that I might need 64 bit integers support. This project uses jsoncpp project (https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) internally, but it seems like the version of jsoncpp inside libjson-rpc-cpp does not support 64 bit integers.

Does anyone know if this is correct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved in version 0.4, which no longer embeds libjsoncpp.

Still, it depends on your building machine whether or not you have 64bit Integer support.